# How to use / refer gradle plugin properties in writing goals?

Tags: gradle, groovy, javadoc

Suppose I wish to use [`destinationDir` property](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.javadoc.Javadoc.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.javadoc.Javadoc:destinationDir) from `Javadoc` gradle plugin. I have the documentation, which just says about property that:

```
File destinationDir
```

How to use this information?

```
javadoc << {

    FileTree docFilesTree = fileTree(dir: 'resources/doc-files')

    File destinationDir

    copy {
        from docFilesTree
        to destinationDir
    }
}
```

I get an error:

> No signature of method:
>   org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.CopySpecWrapper_Decorated.to() is
>   applicable for argument types: (null) values: [null]

apparently meaning that declaration is not the same as initialization in groovy too :)

But how to use this property otherwise?

**UPDATE**

Ok if I do this way:

```
javadoc << {

    FileTree docFilesTree = fileTree(dir: 'resources/doc-files')

    copy {
        from docFilesTree
        into destinationDir
    }    
}
```

it doesn't swear but also doesn't copy anything.

**UPDATE 2**

Actually the explicit question is answered: to refer plugin property, one should just refer it's variable name. But for precision I would like to know if any conditions exist? May be it is possible to refer `destinationDir` only inside `javadoc << {}`? Or it is possible to refer it inside any place in `build.gradle` file once plugin is added?

Comment: Has it found anything? Iterate over `docFilesTree` and log them. Also `destiantioDir` is defined on task not on a plugin.

Comment: Yes, `resources/doc-files` is pointing to incorrect place now, it should be taken from sources location and this will be my next question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> May be it is possible to refer destinationDir only inside javadoc <<
>   {}? Or it is possible to refer it inside any place in build.gradle
>   file once plugin is added?

As I wrote in the comment `destinationDir` is defined on the task not on a plugin, so you can refer to it anywhere with:

```
javadoc.destinationDir
```

It works in `<< {}` since action `{}` is a closure. And if closure does not find a property inside itself it searches for it in `delegate` and then `owner`. In this case delegate is set to task itself. This is actually groovy stuff.